# 403 Forbidden Error on Spring Ajax GET Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Well basically just trying to implement some ajax into my spring web application. For testing purposes I have tried writing some code just to retrieve 'user' information based on their personal 'id' values when they press a link/button. I am assuming that it is a Server side error, that something is wrong with my controller, although I am not entirely sure and need help getting this to work. This is my current JSP page just for testing:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${user.id}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.username}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.dob}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.authority}"/></td>
            <td>
                <a class="update" href="<c:url value="/viewUser"><c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></c:url>"><button>Update</button></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="delete" href="<c:url value="/deleteUser"><c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></c:url>"><button>Delete</button></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="ajax" href="<c:url value="/ajax"><c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></c:url>">Ajax</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ajax').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost:8080/SDP_v1.7/ajax",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                succes: function(user){
                    alert(user.id + " + " + user.username);
                },
                error:function(user,status,er) { 
                    alert("error: "+user+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("/viewUser")
public String updateUser(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Integer id) {

    User user = usersService.getUser(id);

    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "settings";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return usersService.getUser(id);
}
```

This is my error popping up in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/SDP_v1.7/ajax 403 (Forbidden) jquery.js:5
```

send jquery.js:5
x.extend.ajax jquery.js:5
(anonymous function) users:106
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:4
v.handle

Essentially, I aiming to loading each user's information into a pop-up modal with a form. Although I have to get this step working first. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you coming from a webserver on port 80?  If so, then you are dealing with cross-site scripting issues since being on different ports still counts.  You may want to look at [JSONP with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Edit: [Here is a tutorial.](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/learn-how-to-use-the-jsonp-data-format-with-jquery.html#fbid=B8z89ZOwX1z)

Comment: Yes, well I am running it internally so the port is 8080 at the moment. Is JSONP a way to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First your controller is wrong, your mapping doesn't include a path variable, so what should it map to?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return usersService.getUser(id);
}
```

Second your request is wrong as you are calling /ajax whereas you should be calling something like `/ajax/<userid>` else the controller can never know which user you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ajax').click(function(e){
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                succes: function(user){
                    alert(user.id + " + " + user.username);
                },
                error:function(user,status,er) { 
                    alert("error: "+user+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Third your jsp is wrong as it will generate a URL without the id (no path variable but a request parameter). Use `<spring:url ../>` for ease of use.

```
<a class="ajax" href="<spring:url value="/ajax/{id}"><spring:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></spring:url>">Ajax</a>
```

I strongly suggest a read of [the Spring Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/index.html), the [web chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) should shed light on the matter. It shouldn't matter if the call is made through AJAX or not, first fix your mappings, then add AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have implemented these changes and it appears to be still having the same issue. Any further things I can look at?

Comment: Try to access the url without ajax and see if it produces a response. Calling `http://localhost:8080/SDP_v1.7/ajax/1` (or whatever your id is) should produce a json result. If that works it must be your ajax call else your spring configuration. 403 means forbidden do you use Spring Security?

Comment: Yes I do use spring security, although I already allowed the bypass to occur in the configuration.

Comment: <security:intercept-url pattern="/ajax/{id}" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/> That is what my spring security config has. Would that be correct?

Comment: I have tried using POSTMAN the chrome tool to access the URL, although I am getting access denied error. I dont know what else it can possibly be.

Answer (score 0):

```
succes: function(user){
                alert(user.id + " + " + user.username);
            },
```

maybe its SUCCESS instead of succes